# Jndi Lookup in EJB and in its dependencies

Tags: java, ejb, jndi, websphere-8

I have a Java application deployed on Websphere 8.5 as an EAR. I am trying to figure out how do a JNDI lookup from ejb-jar.xml. (Noob to EJB) I typically do JNDI entries lookup from the WAR by adding the entries in web.xml. Now working on a ejb module I figured out I can still do JNDI lookup at ejb bean[1]. See below my ejb-jar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ejb-jar id="ejb-jar_ID" version="2.1"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_2_1.xsd">
<display-name>MyService-ejb</display-name>
<enterprise-beans>
    <message-driven id="MyServiceSyncOutboundCom">
        <ejb-name>MyServiceSyncOutboundcom</ejb-name>
        <ejb-class>
            com.company.MyService.sync.com.MyServiceSyncOutboundCom
        </ejb-class>
        <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
        <message-destination-type>
            javax.jms.Queue
        </message-destination-type>
        <env-entry>
             <env-entry-name>minBalance</env-entry-name>
             <env-entry-type>java.lang.Integer</env-entry-type>
             <env-entry-value>500</env-entry-value>
        </env-entry>
        <env-entry>
        <description></description>
             <env-entry-name>maxCreditBalance</env-entry-name>
             <env-entry-type>java.lang.Integer</env-entry-type>
             <env-entry-value>10000</env-entry-value>
        </env-entry>
    </message-driven>
</enterprise-beans>
```

My question: How do I get these entries into my class now that I have no web.xml ? 
Also if the ejb module comprises of a JAR dependency say `myservice-config.jar` with a `Configs` class, can I retrieve these entries in that class instead of my Message Driven Bean? How does that change the `ejb-jar.xml` file then?
[1] https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/servjndi008.htm

Answer (score 0):

The `ejb-jar.xml` file serves the same purpose for EJBs as the `web.xml` file does for servlets. The XML syntax for injecting into an EJB is the same as the XML syntax for injecting into a servlet, except in `ejb-jar.xml` it is nested in an enterprise-bean, rather than just at the module level.  From your example, it would be something like this:

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>minBalance</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.Integer</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>500</env-entry-value>
    <injection-target>
        <injection-target-class>com.company.MyService.sync.com.MyServiceSyncOutboundCom</injection-target-class>
        <injection-target-name>name of field or method</injection-target-name>
    </injection-target>
</env-entry>
```

You can only inject into classes that will be created by a container; so for example, servlets are created by the Web Container; EJB instances and interceptors are created by the EJB Container.

Your `Configs` class does not appear to be a class that is managed by the container, so cannot be the target of injection. I can think of a couple of options to still inject into it:

1 - In your `ejb-jar.xml`, just declare it to be a singleton bean; then inject your `env-entry` values into it. You could then inject the `Configs` singleton bean into other beans. Although perhaps non-standard, `ejb-jar.xml` can declare any class on the application classpath to be an EJB.

2 - Declare `Confg` to be a CDI managed bean and use the `@Inject` annotation. CDI does not have anything like `web.xml` or `ejb-jar.xml`, so you would have to use annotations when using CDI.